# Where can I download iOS MobileCore SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, ads, publisher

I added an app in MobileCore dashboard, but I've not able to find where to download the SDK for iOS to integrate with my app.
I tried to search through Google but still cannot find a link to download the MobileCore.framework. Do they stop publishing the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted to one of the managers. She told me that they'd stopped support new apps, since they're moving to Supersonic platform soon.